# JWT & Simple Injector. Set connectionstring OnTokenValidated

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, simple-injector

I am new to this kind of concepts so i am kinda stuck on this (explanation of what i aim for a little bellow).

I have the following code in a rest web api:

UnitOfWorkProvider.cs

```
    public class UnitOfWorkProvider : IUnitOfWorkProvider
{
    private readonly Func<AppDbContext> getDbContext;

    public UnitOfWorkProvider(Func<AppDbContext> getDbContext)
    {
        this.getDbContext = getDbContext;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork Get()
    {
        return new AppUnitOfWork(this.getDbContext());
    }
}
```

SimpleInjectorConfiguration.cs

```
        internal static void Configure(this Container container, IConfigurationRoot configuration, IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        InitializeInjectorContainer(container, configuration, app, loggerFactory, httpContextAccessor, memoryCache);
    }

    private static void InitializeInjectorContainer(Container container, IConfigurationRoot configuration, IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        container.Register<IUnitOfWorkProvider>(() => new UnitOfWorkProvider(() => new AppDbContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext"))), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        ...
    }
```

that is called on Startup.cs

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        // Configure and register Simple Injector
        simpleInjectorContainer.Configure(configuration, app, loggerFactory, httpContextAccessor, memoryCache);
        ...
    }
```

What i am for is register the IUnitOfWorkProvider like this in SimpleInjectorConfiguration.cs:

```
container.Register<IUnitOfWorkProvider>();
```

and instantiate it later on JWT OnTokenValidated event when i get the database name from the claims in request:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        // get database name from claims in request

                        // something like this to set the context. this doesnt work.
                        container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWorkProvider>(() => new UnitOfWorkProvider(() => new AppDbContext(SetConnectionString(dbNameFromClaim))), Lifestyle.Scoped);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Many thanks to whom might help me! :)